# Higher dimensional analogue of the Lakes of Wada

Tags: general-topology

Is there a higher dimensional analogue of the Lakes of Wada in $3$, $4$, or more dimensions? For those who don't know, the Lakes of Wada are three disjoint connected open sets in the real plane with the property that all three share the same boundary.

Comment: I believe one of the comments on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723666/in-mathbbrn-how-many-disjoint-open-sets-can-share-a-boundary?rq=1 answer this.

Comment: Just take the product of the 2d example with $R^{n-2}$ and get an example in $ R^n$.